# facebook login with PHP cURL redirect and cookie problems

Tags: php, facebook, curl, authentication

I code a simple PHP cURL facebook login. I face few problems.

1. both localhost and in website my code work but its not redirect to facebook.com.
2. both localhost and in website facebook block the login but in localhost its show me its logged in and showing all facebook content. (Link 1) 
   but not showing on website.(Link 2) 
   and when login from facebook.com then facebook say blocked (Link 3). this cause location problem. thats means my code work but not redirect and facebook blocked for different locations.

Now how can i solve his problems ?? my code below

Note: I can't post more than 2 link, so i paste links and cookie code on pastebin.com.

LOGIN CODE:

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init(); //initialize

/*set login info*/
$info['email'] = 'md60541@gmail.com'; //email or phone
$info['pass']  = 'fake1538id'; //password

$data = http_build_query($info); //declear login info

/* cURL Stacture*/
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //transfer ture
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); //get user agent from broser
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php'); //login url
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, getcwd().'/cookie.txt'); //cookie files
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  getcwd().'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_POST , 1); //method
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); // set post data
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); //set SSL veriyfication false
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_exec($ch); //execute info

/*After login*/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.facebook.com"); //redirect to
$isOK = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_exec($ch)); // for check if login okk.
echo $isOK;
curl_close($ch); //close curl login
```

?>

Cookie content:
http://pastebin.com/raw/3h5ereMQ

Comment: You are not supposed to login that way, Using any such automated tools is explicitly against Facebook ToS. If you want to interact with Facebook - use their API.

Comment: I do understood, thank you!